# How to replace struts with ext.js 6?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, extjs, struts

We want to remove struts and introduce ExtJS. I have searched on internet and with whatever limited knowledge I have about ExtJS, I came to know that we can use [ext direct](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/backend_connectors/direct/specification.html)
but, I don't think it will be allowed in the project.

We also don't want to go with the old route of directly interacting with java servlets.

My question may appear vague but, it is due to the limited knowledge I have on this subject.

I would like to know, should we go with Spring mvc or is there any better alternative?

Comment: They're *entirely* different things; you cannot "replace" Struts (a server-side MVC framework) with ExtJS (a client-side UI framework). You can use ExtJS *with* Struts (or without) and consume JSON (and other) data. It's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: We are planing to move away from Struts 1.2 due to the security vulnaribilites it has. It was suggested to use ext.js but no information was provided on what we should have instead of Struts.
We can migrate to Spring MVC or have Spring DWR but then I am not sure will it be correct fit. I know that my question will attract different opinion but, experts in Stackoverflow community will have better opinion.

Comment: You could do just about anything on the back end I guess.